# How to use native client-side libraries in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, libraries, meteorite

Current Meteor version:
Preview 0.6.6.3

I am tying to add client libraries in my Meteor project (on Ubuntu and also on Windows) with Meteor or meteorite, such as [Taggle.js](http://sean.is/poppin/tags).
Those libraries are not available as packages on Atmosphere.

I tried to copy and paste my `*.js` in the `.meteor/local/build/programs/client` or `.meteor/local/build/programs/client/app` but it didn't work.

How can I put client-side native libraries in my Meteor project?

My current application structure:

> `my_app/`
>
> - `css/`
> - `pages/`
> - `js/`
> - `.meteor/`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You shouldn't manually mess with files in `.meteor` directory (except for `packages` and `release` files), that's where Meteor puts its compiled files. All libraries should go to source folder - so basically anywhere else.

I assume those are client-side libraries.

In that case, put them:

- in `/client` if it doesn't matter when they are loaded and they happen to work there;
- in `/client/lib` if you need to load them before the rest of the code;
- in `/client/compatibility` if the code is not prepared to work with Meteor and you don't want to / don't know how to fix it;
- in `/client/lib/compatibility` if both of the above conditions occur. **I'd recommend to put them here on the beginning just to be safe.**

Comment: As of Meteor v1.0 only `client/compatibility` can be used for libraries that relies on global variables, `client/lib/compatibility` wraps global variable as file-local as any other Meteor project folder

Comment: I have edited the question, some phrasing in your answer may make a bit less sense ("_I assume those are client-side libraries._" for example, I made that clear in the question).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load HTML/CSS/JS files **dynamically** to your meteor application then you can use: **[Meteor-external-file-loader](https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader)**

Add [Meteor-external-file-loader](https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader) to your meteor app by  typing in console:

`meteor add mrt:external-file-loader`

Comment: The latest commit to that project was two years ago and meteorite is effectively dead today.