# How do we use something with Meteor that isn't available as a package?

Tags: meteor

We want to use Winstrap, http://winstrap.azurewebsites.net which is a bootstrap theme, in a Meteor app but it has no package on Atmosphere.  Does anyone know how we can use something in our app which is not a Meteor package?

thanks very much!

Comment: make your own package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor add Js client libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860903/meteor-add-js-client-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own package or directly put library into your project. Either way will work for you. 
For how to create your own package, here is the reference:

> https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing

Comment: [This article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/wrapping-npm-packages/) on wrapping npm packages may also be handy. If you do go through the trouble to do this the community will no doubt appreciate you posting the new package to [atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com).